# Updating $scope in Controller does not update Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angular 1.4:

- I set a variable in my Controller called `$scope.sentence`.
- I have my directive reference `$scope.sentence`
- I change `$scope.sentence` in the Controller.

Expected:

- I expect my directive, to also update to the new value.

Actual:

- The directive doesn't fire again. It never updates.

I made a small sample code here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/b1wPEenHTHdWKCudVoBu?p=preview

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Change `element.html()` to `scope.sentence` in your `$timeout`.

Answer (score 3):

After change content of `<div testdirective>` to `Goodbye World`, the content of `<div testdirective>` not {{sentence}}. So it not change value when you click button `Change Back to Hello`
You should use follow code:

```
  $timeout(function() {
      scope.sentence = 'Goodbye World';
    }, 1000)
```